# Windows 8.1 doesn't recognize ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot

For past few days I only had ubuntu 14.04 installed. I made 4 partitions.
1st - for installing ubuntu, 
2nd - for swap, 
3rd - for /Home, 
4th - as free space for installing windows. 
Now, after installing windows 8.1, I am not getting any option to boot ubuntu. Windows automatically boots on starting the computer.
How do I resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I always install Windows first, then Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue after installing Windows, it installs its own boot loader which is not Linux friendly. Provided Windows hasn't overwritten your Ubuntu install (which it can do, depending on how you installed) then you can boot from the 'boot repair disk' and select 'automatic repair'. Have a google for boot repair disk. It is also worth noting that in order to dual boot into Windows and Ubuntu you have to disable secure boot in the BIOS (EUFI) and you have to turn off fast startup within Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try booting from Ubuntu live image and run boot-repair.
choose the recommended repair and the grub menu will appear after you reboot.